# Authentication using API .net core

Tags: asp.net, api, cookies, asp.net-core

I have the following setup. A Web API that uses Identity and Token Authorization, containing the whole User Management and ofcourse some extra API calls.

Further I am building a FE to consume the API again with .net core. I have my Login form and post to the FE which uses RestSharp to do an API request giving the credentials I got from the form. And I receive some User Data and the Identity Cookie/Token.
I set the cookie/token to the response and now my FE is able to use that to do other API calls with ajax for example.

But my question is, how do I know that he is still logged in after X minutes? The API calls will get denied if the Cookie/token expired, but how does my FE-BE know that they are no longer valid? Do I check on every request the expiry date? 
[image]

I am asking this mainly to challenge the way I have build my system to avoid any huge security flaws.

Comment: Slightly off topic: I recommend `HttpClient` over RestSharp. It's completely built on async calls with great support for unit testing while RestSharp depends on the older `WebClient` and synchronous calls; at least it did that until recently.

Comment: @thoean thank you for the tip, I will take a look at HttpClient, I just found RestSharp easier to use. Also PostMan has auto translate into RestSharp :)

Answer (score 0):

> The API calls will get denied if the Cookie/token expired, but how does my FE-BE know that they are no longer valid? Do I check on every request the expiry date?

To determine whether authorized access has expired, check the `expires_in` time frame that [optionally comes with an OpenID Connect implicit flow response.](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthResponse).

- `access_token`
- `token_type`
- `id_token`
- `state`
- `expires_in` OPTIONAL. Expiration time of the Access Token in seconds since the response was generated.

Since an access_token is usually opaque to the client, the only other way to find out whether access has expired is to ask the issuer of the access_token.

> But my question is, how do I know that he is still logged in after X minutes?

To determine whether your user is still logged in, use the `id_token` not the `access_token`.

Comment: thnx I got it working now I will put my solution as an answer and It would be great if you took a look at the answer. (hope to be able to clean up the code soon)

Answer (score 0):

After some talk with a friend, the solution that is more appropriate (in my opinion) is the following. (the code can be cleaned up)

```
        //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do a rest call to the API
            Uri _baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");
            var client = new RestClient(_baseUri + "api/Account/login");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("postman-token", "7ee2a21b-70d5-8a68-f0dd-518b8a61ddbf");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Email=blah%40gmail.com&password=a1Aa1Aa1A!&=", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            // Check the response
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                // Grab the cookie for the Identity
                // this can be replaced by a token in the future
                String cookie = response.Cookies.Where(c => c.Name == ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application").First().Value;
                // Store the cookie value to use it in sub-sequent requests                
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("IdentityCookieId", cookie);


                // Add claims to our new user, an example Name and an example Role 
                const string Issuer = "http://blah.com";
                var claims = new List<Claim>();
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "AnonymUser", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("SecuredLoggedIn");
                userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                // Sign in the user creating a cookie with X ammount of Expiry
                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal,
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
                        IsPersistent = false,
                        AllowRefresh = false
                    });

                // Move back to the ReturnUrl or for me always to the dashboard
                return RedirectToLocal("/dashboard");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Ofcourse you must edit the `Startup.cs` file under `ConfigureServices` to add `services.AddAuthorization();` before your `AddMvc()`.

And under `Configure` add

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });
```

Comment: @ShaunLuttin take a look if you have time.